# Временная сложность методов базовых классов

Tags: java

А существует ли такая сводная таблица, в которой можно посмотреть временную сложность методов у классов, реализованных в стандартных библиотеках java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для методов стандартных коллекций сводная табличка есть [тут](https://github.com/benblack86/java-snippets/blob/master/resources/java_collections.pdf). Вообще не всегда временная сложность специфицирована. Например, `String.substring` до Java 1.7.0_6 работал с константной сложностью, а после — с линейной от длины подстроки. Или взять `HashMap`. Амортизированная сложность поиска элемента по ключу вроде бы константа, но можно отравить ключами с одинаковым хэшкодом, ухудшив сложность до линейной. Однако с Java 1.8 если ключи `Comparable` (например, строки), в худшем случае сложность становится логарифмической, а не линейной. В общем, много тонкостей.

Comment: Про ключи с одинаковым хэшкодом есть целая глава у Джошуа Блоха )